# How can I call course name in combobox when i select a department in a combobox?

Tags: java, combobox, action

I have two tables in my database as semester table and course table.There are semesterId,courseId,courseName and Sdepartment(department name)in semester table.Course table has courseId and courseName. I have two comboboxes my jframe.First one is for select a department.Second one is select course.I want to select course as to selected department. How can i call course name in combobox when i select a department?I think i should use addActionlistener and actionperformed but i dont know how I use with this code Here my code;

```
   public void coursename(){
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
 session.beginTransaction();
 //Query query= session.createQuery("select a.courseName,e.semesterId from Semester e inner join e.course as a"); 
 Query query= session.createQuery("FROM Senior.entity.Semester S  ");
 //for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
  //Object  row[] = (Object[])   it.next();
  //combocourse.addItem(new CourseItem((String)row[0], (int)row[1]));
  //}  
 List <Semester>re= query.list(); 
 if (re.size() > 0){ 
 Iterator iterate= re.iterator(); 
 final Semester resultAccount= (Semester)iterate.next(); 
 combocourse.removeAllItems();
 for(Semester inv:re){
 combocourse.addItem(new CourseItem(inv.getSemesterId(),inv.getSCourse()));
 }        
 }
  session.close();
```

}

```
  public void depart(){
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
 session.beginTransaction();

 Query query= session.createQuery("FROM Senior.entity.Semester f "); 
 List <Semester>results= query.list(); 
 if (results.size() > 0){ 
 Iterator iterate= results.iterator(); 
 final Semester resultAccount= (Semester)iterate.next(); 
 combodepart.removeAllItems();
 for(Semester inv:results){
 combodepart.addItem(new DepartItem(inv.getSemesterId(),inv.getSDepartment()));

     //  combodepart.addActionListener(combocourse); 
           /*
        @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          JComboBox combocourse;
         combocourse = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
     //     Object selected = combocourse.getSelectedItem();
      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
 session.beginTransaction();

 Query query= session.createQuery("FROM Senior.entity.Semester f "); 
 List <Semester>results= query.list(); 
 if (results.size() > 0){ 
 Iterator iterate= results.iterator(); 
 final Semester resultAccount= (Semester)iterate.next(); 
 combodepart.removeAllItems();
 for(Semester inv:results){
 combodepart.addItem(new DepartItem(inv.getSemesterId(),inv.getSDepartment()));
     }
 });

 */

 }        
 }
 session.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
public class ComboBoxDemo ... implements ActionListener {
    . . .
        departments.addActionListener(this);
    . . .
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String department= (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        updateCourse(department);
    }
    . . .
}
```

You can get the selected item in this method and accordingly you can populate course combo box.

[Here is the link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) to get you started